# NameError: name 'pip' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am unable to use the pip command. Every time I try I am met with the following error:

```
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined
```

I'm using CMD and Python 3.8. I'm almost certain that `C:\python\scripts` is in my path. Yet the pip command continues to elude my capabilities. I've read several articles and threads about other people who've had this problem and those solutions still fail to help me.

Copy Paste from CMD:

```
C:\Windows\System32>py

Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> pip

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pip' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact error message you get, when you try?

Comment: Could you share a picture of your error?

Comment: Can  you please post the output of `echo %PATH%` from CMD, just to make sure?

Answer (score 9):

> Yes, I'm using CMD

That might be the case, but are you sure you don't have python running in it? Try entering `exit()` or `exit`, and then run your pip command.

If you are sure python is not running in youe CMD,
An easy solution that may be less convenient:
You can enter the command `cd C:\python\scripts` and then run your pip command.

Comment: I use python or py, then try pip or python -m pip etc.

Answer (score 5):

#### this worked for me

py -m pip install somepackage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Run

`python -m ensurepip`

or

`python -m ensurepip --upgrade`

if you have python3 rather than python installed, you may need to run this command using python3:

`python3 -m ensurepip`

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html

Answer (score -2):

The same error with Python 3.8
installed on Windows 7 (32-bit) last week.

Not sure how to copy error message from the console since mouse select, copy not supported within the console.

> > sending as answer since commenting not active

Python 3.8 and pip.exe sit in the following directories

C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe

C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe

(edited)

Just implemented select/copy/paste to Python terminal

===

--- pip

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

NameError: name 'pip' is not defined

---

and the answer

You need to add environment variable to point to a directory including pip

Full instructions come from this site:

How to Fix PIP Is Not Recognized in Windows Command Prompt? [MiniTool Tips]

https://www.minitool.com/news/pip-is-not-recognized.html